# Running Docker on Ubuntu docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, containers, dockerfile

I'm having trouble getting Docker CE to run on an Ubuntu Docker image. Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce

RUN docker info
```

The last command fails with the following:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

If I attempt to run `dockerd` from the container, it comes back with the following:

```
ERRO[2018-04-12T14:35:43.945962200Z] 'overlay2' is not supported over overlayfs
INFO[2018-04-12T14:35:43.974187900Z] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds
INFO[2018-04-12T14:35:43.976355700Z] Loading containers: start.
WARN[2018-04-12T14:35:43.978060300Z] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: , error: exec: "modprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
WARN[2018-04-12T14:35:43.978173000Z] Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message: ``, error: exec: "modprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
WARN[2018-04-12T14:35:43.978965200Z] Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: ``, error: exec: "modprobe": executable file not found in $PATH
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

I assume there is something missing in the kernel for the `ubuntu` image?

Here's the output of `uname -a`, from the container:

```
root@85bdefe67e4a:/# uname -a
Linux 85bdefe67e4a 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 15:12:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is it something wrong with the `ubuntu:16.04` container or is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: just for more clarifications, why would you run docker inside a docker's container?

Comment: today I will answer your question with a working bare bones docker in docker which I have working fine in production ... the approach is to NOT install docker inside a container instead sideload docker so docker commands are enabled from inside a container ... @hichamx asks Why ? because my cloud hosting provider cannot give me root in production so I do all my root installs for things like a github webhook server install which launches my docker image rebuild and relaunch from inside my devops container ... transparent, maintainable and without any 3rd party CI vendor middle man monstrosity

Comment: For my purposes (building and pushing a Docker image from a BitBucket pipeline) I realised that BitBucket already has this functionality pretty much in the configuration @ScottStensland mentioned: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html

Answer (score 2):

This has already been done. It is called docker in docker.

The Docker image already exists on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) and you can check the source code under [dind](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind/blob/master/Dockerfile).